# Trouble using MySQL JOINS

Tags: mysql, database, left-join, inner-join

I'm getting info of sales by date with this code:

```
SELECT product.product_id, product.product_brand_id, product.product_model_id, product.product_subcategory_id, product.product_retail_price, product.product_wholesale_price, SUM(product_sold.product_quantity) AS product_quantity_sold, SUM(product_sold.product_total_price) AS total_price_sold 
FROM product
INNER JOIN product_sold 
  ON product.product_id = product_sold.product_id AND product.product_subcategory_id = '$subcategory_id'
INNER JOIN sales
  ON sales.sales_id = product_sold.product_sales_id
WHERE sales.sales_approved = '1' AND sales.sales_approved_time > '$start_timestamp' AND sales.sales_approved_time < '$end_timestamp'
GROUP BY product.product_id 
ORDER BY SUM(product_sold.product_quantity) DESC
```

This  above code is pulling the info correctly, but when I tried to get info of product sold and also unsold I run this code:

```
SELECT product.product_id, product.product_brand_id, product.product_model_id, product.product_subcategory_id, product.product_retail_price, product.product_wholesale_price, SUM(product_sold.product_quantity) AS product_quantity_sold, SUM(product_sold.product_total_price) AS total_price_sold, product_brand.brand_name, product_model.model_name, product_subcategory.subcategory_name
FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_sold 
  ON product.product_id = product_sold.product_id AND product.product_subcategory_id = '$subcategory_id'
LEFT JOIN sales 
  ON sales.sales_id = product_sold.product_sales_id AND sales.sales_approved = '1' AND sales.sales_approved_time > '$start_timestamp' AND sales.sales_approved_time < '$end_timestamp'
INNER JOIN product_brand 
  ON product_brand.brand_id = product.product_brand_id
INNER JOIN product_model 
  ON product_model.model_id = product.product_model_id
INNER JOIN product_subcategory 
  ON product_subcategory.subcategory_id = product.product_subcategory_id
WHERE product.product_subcategory_id = '$subcategory_id'
GROUP BY product.product_id 
ORDER BY SUM(product_sold.product_quantity) DESC, product_brand.brand_name ASC, product_model.model_name ASC
```

When I run that code works but not by date, it takes all the data from the database and show the info.

What I need is show products that have been sold and then add a kind of subquery to also show products that haven't been sold.

---

THE FINAL SOLUTION I FOUND IS THIS.

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_brand_id, p.product_model_id, p.product_subcategory_id, p.product_retail_price, p.product_wholesale_price, SUM(IFNULL(ps.product_quantity,0)) AS product_quantity_sold,SUM(IFNULL(ps.product_total_price,0)) AS total_price_sold, pb.brand_name, pm.model_name, psub.subcategory_name
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_sold ps ON p.product_id = ps.product_id
LEFT JOIN sales s ON ps.product_sales_id = s.sales_id
JOIN product_brand pb ON pb.brand_id = p.product_brand_id
JOIN product_model pm ON pm.model_id = p.product_model_id
JOIN product_subcategory psub ON psub.subcategory_id = p.product_subcategory_id
WHERE p.product_subcategory_id = $subcategory_id
 AND ( s.sales_id IS NULL
   OR ( s.sales_approved = '1' 
      AND s.sales_approved_time > '$start_timestamp'  
      AND s.sales_approved_time < '$end_timestamp'
      )
   )
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY product_quantity_sold DESC, pb.brand_name ASC, pm.model_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably CLOSER to what you want.  I moved the Sales table to the front as that is the basis of your query... the date and sales approved status... From sales, go to the product sold joined by the sales ID... THEN go to the product table and its related sub-tables as needed.  May need some minor adjusting, but should put you on the right path.

```
SELECT 
      p.product_id, 
      p.product_brand_id, 
      p.product_model_id, 
      p.product_subcategory_id, 
      p.product_retail_price, 
      p.product_wholesale_price, 
      SUM(ps.product_quantity) AS product_quantity_sold, 
      SUM(ps.product_total_price) AS total_price_sold, 
      pb.brand_name, 
      pm.model_name, 
      psub.subcategory_name
   FROM 
      sales s 
         JOIN product_sold ps
            s.sales_id = ps.product_sales_id
            JOIN product p
               ON ps.product_id = p.product_id 
               AND p.product_subcategory_id = '$subcategory_id'
               INNER JOIN product_brand pb
                  ON p.product_brand_id = pb.brand_id
               INNER JOIN product_model pm
                  ON p.product_model_id = pm.model_id 
               INNER JOIN product_subcategory psub 
                  ON p.product_subcategory_id = psub.subcategory_id
   WHERE 
          s.sales_approved = '1' 
      AND s.sales_approved_time > '$start_timestamp' 
      AND s.sales_approved_time < '$end_timestamp'
   GROUP BY 
      p.product_id 
   ORDER BY 
      SUM(ps.product_quantity) DESC, 
      pb.brand_name, 
      pm.model_name
```

Here is another query that does by ALL Products, and if any qualifying sales, gets that too... unlike above was specific to all qualifying sales first.  Notice that there is a sub-query on the sales, product sales and products per its own where clause and sum/group by so its already grouped to a single record per product ID.  That is joined to your overall product table...

```
SELECT 
      p.product_id, 
      p.product_brand_id, 
      p.product_model_id, 
      p.product_subcategory_id, 
      p.product_retail_price, 
      p.product_wholesale_price, 
      SUM(SummedSales.product_quantity_sold) AS product_quantity_sold, 
      SUM(SummedSales.total_price_sold) AS total_price_sold, 
      pb.brand_name, 
      pm.model_name, 
      psub.subcategory_name
   FROM 
      product p
         INNER JOIN product_brand pb
            ON p.product_brand_id = pb.brand_id
         INNER JOIN product_model pm
            ON p.product_model_id = pm.model_id 
         INNER JOIN product_subcategory psub 
            ON p.product_subcategory_id = psub.subcategory_id
         LEFT JOIN ( select
                           ps.product_id,
                           SUM(ps.product_quantity) AS product_quantity_sold, 
                           SUM(ps.product_total_price) AS total_price_sold
                        from
                           sales s
                              JOIN product_sold ps
                                 ON s.sales_id = ps.product_sales_id
                                 JOIN product p
                                    ON ps.product_id = p.product_id 
                                    AND p.product_subcategory_id = '$subcategory_id'
                        WHERE 
                               s.sales_approved = '1' 
                           AND s.sales_approved_time > '$start_timestamp' 
                           AND s.sales_approved_time < '$end_timestamp' ) SummedSales
            ON P.productID = SummedSales.product_id
   GROUP BY 
      p.product_id 
   ORDER BY 
      SUM(SummedSales.product_quantity_sold) DESC, 
      pb.brand_name, 
      pm.model_name
```

Comment: The query is correct, but how can I also add a subquery of some type to also display products that havent been sold?

Comment: well and @bmacuer you both may want to read http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/ ? because off MySQL GROUP BY extended "feature" this may give you trouble

Comment: @bmacuer, see revision to answer and second query to do ALL Products, and sales per qualified products of the date range.

Comment: Thanks for your help! it does work. I found an easier way of doing it... here you can see it in the revision to question or in this pastie: http://pastie.org/8529798